# In Outlook Addin, how do I determine that an email's Sender is a shared mailbox when AutoMapping is disabled?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-interop

In a previous question, I had asked something similar and received a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69879763/3526156

However, I found out recently that this solution will not work if the user has automapping disabled like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/profiles-and-accounts/remove-automapping-for-shared-mailbox#procedure because it will prevent the shared mailbox from appearing under the `AlternativeMailbox` node in AutoDiscover XML.

May I know is there any way to fix it? This is my code

```
public bool isSharedMailboxAccount(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mail)
{
    string fromEmail = mail.Sender.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E").ToString();
    bool isShared = false; //If true, then it means it is a shared mailbox

    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Account acc in mail.Session.Accounts)
    {
        //using XMLDocument to query AutoDiscoverXML value
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(acc.autoDiscoverXml);
        
        XmlNodeList alts = xml.GetElementsByTagName("AlternativeMailbox");
        foreach (XmlNode alt in alts)
        {
            //NOTE: I'm not entirely sure that alt mailboxes that has Type == Delegate will always mean shared mailbox but so far in my tests, it seems to be so.
            if(alt.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>().Where(e => e.LocalName == "Type").First().InnerText.Equals("Delegate"))
            {
                if(alt.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>().Where(e => e.LocalName == "SmtpAddress").First().InnerText.Equals(fromEmail))
                {
                    isShared = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        
        if(isShared)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return isShared;
}
```